# solidity: Loop through array of struct -> only looping to first array member

Tags: solidity, struct

I'm using a struct to hold invoice data. After the invoice data has been submitted, i want to execute some code for the invoices that aren't due.

My current code is this:

```
contract mycontract {
      
    uint sender;
    uint transactiondate;
    uint dueDate;
    uint counter;
    
    struct myStruct {
        uint amount;
        address sender;
        uint transactiondate;
        uint dueDate;
    }
    
    myStruct[] public invoices; //create array from struct
    
    mapping(address => myStruct[]) public userInvoices;
    
   
    function addInvoice (uint amount, uint _dueDate) public {
        transactiondate = block.timestamp;
        dueDate = block.timestamp + (_dueDate * 1 days);
        userInvoices[msg.sender].push(myStruct(amount, msg.sender, transactiondate, dueDate));
        myStruct memory invoiceData = myStruct(amount, msg.sender, transactiondate, dueDate);
        invoices.push(invoiceData);
    }
    
    function getInvoices() public view returns(myStruct[] memory) {
        return invoices;
    }
    
   function getArrayLength() public view returns(uint) {
       uint arrayLength = invoices.length;
       return arrayLength;
   }
   
   function showUserInvoices() public view returns (myStruct[] memory) {
       return userInvoices[msg.sender];
   }
    
  
    
    // loop
    function loopInvoices() public view returns(string memory) {
        uint arrayLength = invoices.length;
        for (uint i=0; i<arrayLength; i++) {
            if (block.timestamp <= invoices[i].dueDate) {
                return 'Invoice not due yet';
            } 
        }
    }

    
}
```

The code works, but only yields 1 string as return, even when I've created multiple invoices. Of course I want to loop the entire array of invoices. I thought the current code would do this, but I seem to be missing something.

Already Googled a lot, but couldn't find a solution to this specific question.

So TIA for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The code has at least two problems.

1. The function `addInvoice` creates two copies of every invoice.

   ```
   userInvoices[msg.sender].push(myStruct(amount, msg.sender, transactiondate, dueDate));
   myStruct memory invoiceData = myStruct(amount, msg.sender, transactiondate, dueDate);
   invoices.push(invoiceData);
   ```

   One is pushed to `userInvoices[msg.sender]` and the other is pushed to `invoices`.
2. Using return inside the loop of `loopInvoices` will cause the function to terminate immediately. If you want to skip the invoices not due yet, use `continue` to keep looping:

   ```
    uint arrayLength = invoices.length;
    for (uint i=0; i<arrayLength; i++) {
        if (block.timestamp <= invoices[i].dueDate) {
            continue;
        } else {
            // Do something with invoice[i]
        }
    }
   ```

The other issue is that using unbounded loops might cause a DoS because of out of gas condition.